# Undo all history for one file in one branch

Tags: git

I have created a `git` feature branch in git and worked through several commits that have been pushed to the remote repository on the same branch. Early in my development I added sensitive data into a file that was committed and pushed. I don't want to remove this file from the branch and history, I just want to remove all historical changes in that branch from the file and remote repository.

Essentially I want to make it as if I had never made any changes to one file in my source tree in any commit in a branch but leave all other changes as is.

Is there a `git filter-branch` construct I can use for this? How do I assure the changes are removed from the remote branch as well?

Comment: Are you trying to remove sensitive data?

Comment: I'm trying to remove sensitive data from a file that contains other data that I don't want to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `git filter-branch`.  The easiest thing is to use a `tree-filter`.  (You could get better performance by setting up an `index-filter`, but that seems harder for this operation, and for a small repo `tree-filter` should be fine.)

```
 git filter-branch --tree-filter 'if test -f path/to/file; then git checkout master -- path/to/file; fi' -- --all
```

---

**UPDATE** - I just realized I only answered half of your question.

> How do I assure the changes are removed from the remote branch as well?

You'll end up having to force-push all affected branches.  This is (obviously) a history rewrite, so you'll need to coordinate with anyone else who has a copy of the repo.

Ideally before you start you want them to push all their work to origin, then discard their clones; then you do the rewrite; then everyone clones again.  If you can't do that, then you can instead treat it as an "upstream rebase" (see the `git rebae` docs), but realize that means everyone still has a copy of the sensitive information.

In fact, if others might have accessed the remote, you might as well just treat all the sensitive info in the repo as compromised.  Sorry, but you can't unbreak  a bottle.

But assuming you still want to try to eliminate the copies of the information, the trouble is that rewriting the history isn't enough to remove the data from the repos' databases.  So the info currently resides in

1) your local repo

2) the remote

3) the local of anyone who's cloned the remote

You have no real control over (3) - which is why you probably just need to consider the information compromised.  Generally speaking the easiest way to handle (2) is by deleting and recreating the repo (though depending on how the remote is hosted you may have other options).

You do have more options for (1), but again the easiest thing is to replace the local repo, i.e. by re-cloning it.  For example, after you've done the history rewrite locally

```
cd ..
git clone file://localhost/path/to/rewritten/repo clean_repo
```

And then rebuild everything from `clean_repo`